# How to fix this, i try to load dashboard route when the auth middleware is true

Tags: laravel, session, routes, middleware

But when authentication was success, it shown error Route [/db1] not defined. I hace declared db1 route, but this route can access only if user has session. Anyone can tell me what wrong with my code?

this is my route:
`Route::group(['middleware' => ['userSession']], function() {     Route::get('/db1', [WasteController::class, 'db1'])->name('db1'); });`

this is my kernel in middlewareGroup:
`'userSession' => [             \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserSession::class,         ],`

this is my middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) { 
   if ($request->session()->get('status') != 'true') {  
      //status user cannot be found in session 
      return redirect('/'); 
   }   
   return $next($request);
}
```

i have tried but it show error db1 route not defined

Comment: Did you clear the route cache after adding the route with `php artisan route:cache` ?

Comment: The title of this question is too broad, it should summarise the topic your question is about. For example "Laravel middleware authentication" (this isn't a good title either, but I don't know enough about Laravel to provide a better one).

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the route right? Can you show us how you do that?

Comment: Did you check brother's user info is saved in session before this middleware called?

Comment: list your all available routes using this command in terminal , php artisan route:list

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) { 
   if ($request->session()->get('status') = 'true') {  
      //status user cannot be found in session 
       return $next($request);
   }
   return redirect('/');
   
}
```